# NodeJS truncating POST request body to server

Tags: node.js, http, stream, buffer

I have the following code:

```
const http = require('http');
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const hostname = 'hostname';
const port = 3000;
const path = '/my/path';
const method = 'POST';

const body = JSON.stringify(VERYLARGEJSONOBJECT); // 343700+ bytes in size

console.log(`Sending ${body.length} bytes:`);

const options = {
hostname,
port,
path,
method,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': body.length
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`Response statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
});

const stream = Readable.from([body]);

stream.pipe(req);

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

When I send it from my desktop (x64, 16GB RAM) it sends even the largest of JSON objects just fine. But when I send it from an old i3 laptop (8GB RAM) the JSON object gets cut off, and cannot be parsed by the receiving server.

I think this has to do with the stream that I'm using to buffer the output (since `req.write` gets saturated very quickly), but can't figure out exactly where I'm going wrong.

I know that it is this sending code that is wrong, as I can send the same JSON object using postman, or using the exact same code on my desktop to the server and it works just fine.

I have also tried cutting up the JSON data with:

```
  const body = JSON.stringify(VERYLARGEJSONOBJECT); // 343700+ bytes in size
  var re = new RegExp('.{1,' + 512 + '}', 'g');
  const packetChunks = body.match(re);

...

  const stream = Readable.from(packetChunks);
```

But it did not help

Edit:

Upon further investigation, it seems only the last 3 characters are missing, only when called on the i3 machine, which is very strange.
The client is sending `"inetLatency":17.996}` as the last part of the JSON packet, but the server is receiving `"inetLatency":17.9`. I have tried adding a `req.write('   ');` (which is returning `true`) at the end and also not calling `req.end()` to see if that'd make the server receive the trailing data, but it still doesn't receive anything.

Changing the stringify line to `const body = JSON.stringify(sendData) + '    ';` does ensure that the last 3 characters of the JSON object are received, but I don't like this hack because it doesn't fix the underlining problem.

Comment: try these two lines:
1. In header
`'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)` 

2. at the end directly use write or use stream (buffer object)
`req.write(postData);`
`req.end();`

Comment: @ArjunSingh Thank you! That was it. How come `body.length` didn't work?